# Why am I getting a blank image as my output?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

Here's some code I wrote to display the magnitude spectrum of an image:

```
orig_imdata = imread('Original_Image.png'); 
spec_orig = fft2(double(orig_imdata));
spec_orig2 = abs(spec_orig); 
spec_img = fftshift(spec_orig2);
imshow(spec_img);
```

When I comment out the use of `abs` and just `fftshift` the image, I get an image, albeit with the phase and the magnitude. If I apply the `abs` function right after using `fftshift`, I get a blank result from `imshow`. I need an image of the magnitude of the spectral analysis of my image.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image isn't "blank" at all. `imshow` is designed so that any `double` precision values that are less than 0 are displayed as black and any values larger than 1 are displayed as white.  When computing the magnitude components of the image, you are producing `double` precision images in your code.

Therefore, I highly suspect that because most of your components (if not *all*) are greater than 1, this gives you a visualization of an entirely white and therefore "blank" image.  Now that we've found the problem, however you're [not out of the woods yet](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+out+of+the+woods).  Simply scaling your components so that they fit in the range of `[0,1]` won't help either.  If you do this, the magnitude spectrum's DC component will probably be so large that it's overwhelming the rest of the magnitude components in your image.  Therefore, you'll only see one white dot in the middle and the rest of the image will be black.

A common practice is to apply a `log` operation to the magnitude spectrum for display, then rescaling the values so that they fit in the range of `[0,1]`:

```
%// Your code
orig_imdata = imread('Original_Image.png'); 
spec_orig = fft2(double(orig_imdata));
spec_orig2 = abs(spec_orig); 
spec_img = fftshift(spec_orig2);

%// New code
spec_img_log = log(1 + spec_img);
imshow(spec_img_log,[]);
```

In the `log` operation, the huge dynamic range of values gets compressed to a smaller range, especially when the values get larger, and so naturally scaling to `[0,1]` of this compressed range will give you better visual results.

The reason why you add 1 to every component then take the `log` is to avoid the `log(0)` operation.  Should any magnitude components be zero, this will evaluate to `log(1)`, which will become 0.  Once you do this, you can use `imshow(...,[])` to rescale the display so that the smallest magnitude component goes to 0 while the largest magnitude component goes to 1 of the **log** spectrum.  Take note that I did **not** modify the original spectrum so you can do your processing on that.  Also, the rescaling done by `imshow` is completely done internally to the call.  It does not rescale the data in anyway - it does this only for display and that's that.

---

Give that a go and see how it goes.

Comment: well the solution works, and once I get through what I need to do, I'll come back and carefully read through why this works. Incredibly well detailed answer! kudos!

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I've added more edits since your accept :)... especially how this scaling works.  You're welcome.  Good luck!  BTW, take a look at the paragraph specifically after the code.  It tells you why it works.

Comment: I assume, I'll be able to clarify any further queries about this answer later on? Thanks once again for this answer!

Comment: @SharanDuggirala You certainly can.  Just drop me a comment here.  You're welcome. Good luck!